# Is it against EU-law to load Google Tag Manager, if I don't do anything with it?

Tags: google-analytics, cookie, gdpr, eu-cookie-law

### Question

**Can I load Google Tag Manager on my page, if I don't record any data before the cookie consent is given from the visitor?**

---

### Context

I have a WordPress installation, with a Vue frontend. I would like to keep all JavaScript inside Vue, which means that adding the GTM-code to the head-section client-side, after a button is clicked will inevitably be quite messy.

So I'm considering to load GTM, but then setup all Analytics and third-party stuff only to fire on a [custom event](https://consent.guide/tag-manager-delayed-script-loading/). That way, the cookies will be redundant cookies until the consent is given. Or what?

Answer (score 1):

Google Tag Manager container code on it's own, does not track anything or use/create any cookies for a site visitor.

> So I'm considering to load GTM, but then setup all Analytics and
>   third-party stuff only to fire on a custom event. That way, the
>   cookies will be redundant cookies until the consent is given. Or what?

One of the joys/advantages of GTM is that it can be used to deploy GA tracking and other 3rd party stuff after a user's consent has been given.